# STM32F401 Hardware design

Tags: power, pcb-design, stm32

Last days i decided to use stm32 chips.I am reading stm32f401 datasheet to design my hardware but below the schematic there is a statement " The 4.7 µF ceramic capacitor must be connected to one of the VDD pin.",do i need to add a parallel capacitor between VDD and GND.Any help or suggestion will be good for me
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a 4.7 uF capacitor between VDD and GND, right at the chip. The 100nF capacitors are also necessary but not enough.

Comment: Hi again ,I have another quick question.how the chip behaves if I remove 100nf capacitors,I am asking this because ,my circuit does not work I have to determine which is burned when i soldering stm32f401 or capacitors.

Comment: No problem! You can also keep but not mount the 10k pullup R2 on NRST, it is pretty useless and not recommended.

Comment: If you remove the 100nF bypass caps, chances are the supply voltage at the chip fluctuates too much when it draws current spikes at the clock frequency and it does not work.

Comment: my stlink does not detect stm32f4 so burned capacitor may be the reason of this ,isnt it

Comment: Don't do silly guesses. There might be a million other reasons. If one cap is broken it should still work, unless it is short circuiting the supply voltage to ground which again you should see with a multimeter that you are missing supply voltage and see quite a lot of short circuit current. You don't say how you connected them but most likely you just did not connect supply voltage reference between ST-link and target.